# How to prevent schema modification by the user in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, authorization, roles, privileges

How to prevent the user from performing schema modification such as adding new tables, deleting table columns etc. while enabling the user to perform the create, read, update and delete operations?

Comment: `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ...` (and `REVOKE ALL` beforehand if necessary)

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-grant.html) there is two possible privileges for schema `CREATE | USAGE`, where CREATE `allows new objects to be created within the schema` (what you need to **prevent**) and USAGE `allows access to objects contained in the specified schema` (what you want to **keep**).

So you need `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA ... FROM ...` and `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ... TO ...`

But, before that, be careful with [privileges granted on PUBLIC](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156607/179992), probably you have to REVOKE all that permissions on PUBLIC and GRANT them to necessary users.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for that is to use two users:

- one that owns the schema and all objects in it
- another one that is granted the necessary permissions on the objects (`USAGE` on the schema and sequences, `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` on the tables, etc.)

You can use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to get the permissions right for all objects created in the future.